# Starting the Pepper Robot Emulator/Robot Viewer crashes Android Studio without error message

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, pepper

I installed the Pepper SDK according to the guide (https://qisdk.softbankrobotics.com/sdk/doc/pepper-sdk/ch1_gettingstarted/installation.html) multiple times now, but as i am starting the Robot Emulator for Pepper or trying to connect to the real robot, Android Studio just closes without any error.
I looked into the Windows Event Viewer and it says the problem is located in qi.dll in C:\Users[name]\AppData\Local\Temp\qi.dll.
The last message in the Event Log says
"QI_WRITABLE_PATH=D:\Softbank Robotics\RobotSDK\API 7/naoqi-config/
D:\Softbank Robotics\RobotSDK\API 7\tools/bin/naoqi-bin.exe --qi-listen-url tcp://127.0.0.1:9570" and the emulator loads to 0-17% before closing.
I already tried to reinstall pretty much everything and different versions, but nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

First, are you running it on [a compatible system](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/pepper-qisdk/getting-started/installing-pepper-sdk-plug#check-compatibility)?

Given that you are on Windows 11, [this troubleshooting section](https://qisdk.softbankrobotics.com/sdk/doc/pepper-sdk/ch1_gettingstarted/installation.html?highlight=troubleshooting#troubleshooting) might apply to your case:

> Connection to a real or virtual robot is impossible and log contains:
>
> `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\[yourUserName]\AppData\Local\Temp\qi.dll`
>
> The error may be caused by space character your session name [yourUserName].

Comment: I have Windows 11 installed, but that should not be the problem, because it's running on my other device with Windows 11.

Comment: Check the troubleshooting for the installation: https://qisdk.softbankrobotics.com/sdk/doc/pepper-sdk/ch1_gettingstarted/installation.html?highlight=troubleshooting#troubleshooting

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help me, i already checked the troubleshooting, but i have no space in my user name and also have not seen this particular error on my device.

Comment: Do you have non-ASCII characters in your user name?

Comment: No, only letters and a dot.

Comment: Does the file `C:\Users\[yourUserName]\AppData\Local\Temp\qi.dll` exist?

Comment: Yes. When i delete it, it still crashes with the same Message in the Event Viewer.

Comment: You could try with a user name with no dot, but frankly I don't know what is wrong. You should probably contact the support.

Comment: Guess i will try that. Thank you anyway!